# Returning data where datetime columns are between user input of date, hours and minuets combined

Tags: mysql

I am having major issues with returning data from my table where dates are between six user inputs. A user can select a from date, from hours, from minuets along with to date, to hours and to minuets.The aim is, if the input is found in the table a Jquery alert is displayed.

My table has two "datetime" cols and contain the start date and time and the end date and time. i.e

Start date and time "2018-09-14 08:00:00"
End date and time: "2018-09-14 16:00:00"

On the user input form I have the following textfields:

- RoomFromDate, date selected from a popup calander. The selected date
  is at this stage in the format of "d-m-Y"
- RoomToDate, date selected from a popup calander. The selected date is
  at this stage in the format of "d-m-Y"
- RoomFromTimeH, selected from a dropdown menu containing times in
  hours from 00 to 23
- RoomToTimeH, selected from a dropdown menu containing times in hours
  from 00 to 23
- RoomFromTimeM, selected from a dropdown menu containing times in
  minuets from 00 to 59
- RoomToTimeM, selected from a dropdown menu containing times in
  minuets from 00 to 59

When the "RoomToTimeM" is selected it triggers a Jquery/Ajax script that posts the query information to a php script "check_record_avail.php" which runs the query and returns the data if a record is found.

Looking at the browser console I can see that the corret user selections are Posted via Ajax to "check_record_avail.php", see below.

```
console.log("Check date and time:",fromdate, fromhours, frommins, todate, tohours, tomins);
FromDate: 14-09-2018
FromTimeHours: 08
FromTimeMins: 00
ToDate: 14-09-2018
ToTimeHours: 16
ToTimeMins: 00
```

In my "check_record_avail.php" script I have the following:

```
if(isset($_POST['FromTimeHours'])){
$FromTime = $_POST['FromTimeHours'];
}
//echo "From time ". $FromTime."<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['FromTimeMins'])){
$FromTimeMins = $_POST['FromTimeMins'];
}
//echo "From time mins ". $FromTimeMins."<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['ToDate'])){
$ToDate = $_POST['ToDate'];
}
//echo "To date ". $ToDate."<br/>";

if(isset($_POST['ToTimeHours'])){
$ToTime = $_POST['ToTimeHours'];
}
if(isset($_POST['ToTimeMins'])){
$ToTimeMins = $_POST['ToTimeMins'];
}

$FromDateTime = $FromDate . " " . $FromTime . ":".$FromTimeMins.":00";
$ToDateTime = $ToDate . " " . $ToTime . ":".$ToTimeMins.":00";

    //With the help of Stackoverflow member "scaisEdge" I have the follwong query:

SELECT ClientName, RoomName, RoomFromDateTime, RoomToDateTime FROM Conf
WHERE HotelID = '".$HotelID."' AND RoomID = '".$RoomID."' AND (RoomFromDateTime
BETWEEN str_to_date('".$FromDateTime ."', '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AND str_to_date('".$ToDateTime."',  '%Y-%m-%d %T' 
OR RoomToDateTime BETWEEN str_to_date('".$FromDateTime ."','%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AND str_to_date('".$ToDateTime."','%Y-%m-%d %T' ))
```

If I hard code the selected user input using the following dates and times, From "2018-09-14 08:00:00", To "2018-09-14 16:00:00"  the query looks like this:

```
SELECT ClientName, RoomName, RoomFromDateTime, RoomToDateTime FROM Conf
WHERE HotelID = 'EXBHX' AND RoomID = '3' AND (RoomFromDateTime
BETWEEN str_to_date('2018-09-15 08:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AND str_to_date('2018-09-15 16:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %T' )
OR RoomToDateTime BETWEEN str_to_date('2018-09-15 08:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T' ) AND str_to_date('2018-09-15 16:00:00','%Y-%m-%d %T' ))
```

Running this query returns 1 record.

However, if I change the "$FromTimeHours" to any hours time less than "16", the query returns zero records.

I have even tried converting all the datetimes into UNIX TimeStamps but the results are the same. Can anyone help me solve this issue.

Many thanks in advance of your time.

Comment: The user submits one datetime string for the start of the range , and one for the end. This range is then compared with the data. That's it. None of this str_to_date nonsense

Comment: Incidentally, range A overlaps range B if range A starts before range B finishes, and ends after range B starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ClientName
     , RoomName
     , RoomFromDateTime
     , RoomToDateTime 
  FROM Conf
 WHERE HotelID = 'EXBHX' 
   AND RoomID = 3 
   AND RoomFromDateTime < '2018-09-15 16:00:00'
   AND RoomToDateTime > '2018-09-15 08:00:00'
```

Comment: Hi, it was as simple as that, works perfectly. I did not think to swap the input data around. After many hours trying to get this to work a session has been learned. Many, many thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that you may have to consider what happens if another user submits an insert `while` you're checking